# What does this syntax mean? Is it plain jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I found on codeply an example having the following line:

```
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
```

I think it is related to the line in html:

```
<li>
   <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected">
```

But what does exactly `'[id^=carousel-selector-]'` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the [attribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector.

It will select all the elemets whose id starts with `carousel-selector-`

Consider the html,

```
<a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected">one</a>
<a id="carousel-selector-1" class="selected">one</a>
<a id="carousel-selector-2" class="selected">one</a>
<a id="testcarousel-selector-2" class="selected">one</a>
```

Then `$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').` will return first 3 anchor elements, as its id starts with `carousel-selector-`

1. `^` is starts with selector
2. `$` is ends with selector
3. `*` is contains selector

Comment: I tried, but some time should be passed on SO since the answer is posted. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It means; select element with an ID that begins with `carousel-selector-`

You may also come across a similar selector `id*=carousel-selector-` which means; select elements with an ID that *contains* `carousel-selector-`

Answer (score 1):

the query is going to click all the element whose id is going to start with carousel-selector- . for example

```
 <div id="carousel-selector-1">click me</div>
<p id="carousel-selector-2">click me</p>
<h1 id="carousel-selector-3">click me</h1>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click(function () {
            alert('ok');
        });
    });
</script>
```

There are three different html element with random id but starting with the same id name. so this will find them all and do the event what you want to do
or you can also hide the all item on page load or do whatever you want

```
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').hide();
```

So this will going to search all the item whose id is starting with carousel-selector- and do the stuff